# How can I map boolean data type in Swagger Specification to NSNumber in Objective C client SDK?

Tags: objective-c, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate client SDK in Objective C language. One of my APIs is taking boolean parameter. Parameter is defined in [Swagger Specification](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec) as follows:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "recursive",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "",
        "required": false,
        "type": "boolean"
    }
]
```

The generated client SDK is checking if `BOOL` variabe is `nil`. `BOOL` is a primitive type in Objective C, cannot be checked against `nil`. It is causing compilation error.

```
-(NSNumber*) folderDeleteFolderWithCompletionBlock: (NSString*) path recursive: (BOOL) recursive {
    ...
    if(recursive != nil)
    {
        queryParams[@"recursive"] = recursive;
    }
    ...
}
```

If we use NSNumber `+ (NSNumber *)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value` in place of BOOL, this issue can be fixed. How can I map `boolean` in swagger specification to `NSNumber` in client SDK?

I made few changes in [ObjcClientCodegen.java](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/ObjcClientCodegen.java) like replace following line

```
typeMapping.put("boolean", "BOOL");
```

with

```
typeMapping.put("boolean", "NSNumber");
```

Even I remove `BOOL` from `defaultIncludes` and `languageSpecificPrimitives` HashSets

```
defaultIncludes = new HashSet<String>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    /*"bool",
                    "BOOL",*/
                    "int",
                    "NSString",
                    "NSObject",
                    "NSArray",
                    "NSNumber",
                    "NSDate",
                    "NSDictionary",
                    "NSMutableArray",
                    "NSMutableDictionary")
);
languageSpecificPrimitives = new HashSet<String>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    "NSNumber",
                    "NSString",
                    "NSObject",
                    "NSDate"/*,
                    "bool",
                    "BOOL"*/)
);
```

In-spite this generated client SDK is using BOOL data type instead of NSNumber.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The latest ObjC SDK in [develop2.0 branch](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/develop_2.0) should have the issue resolved. Please take a look.  (later the development will be moved to the `master`)

Comment: Unfortunately problem is still there. `develop_2.0` branch has lot of other issues as well.

Comment: It works for me and Boolean is mapped to NSNumber. Have you tried "mvn clean package" before generating the objc client ?

Comment: `mvn clean package` did the trick. Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) has this issue addressed.